# Constructing a NetCDF where variable consists of data and error data

Tags: python, dataframe, netcdf, python-xarray

Quite a simple question but I cannot seem to find a solution.

I have time dimension, years t1 to t2. Then I have a few variables, lets say [x, y, z] and all of them have error values associated with them. The current CSV file is like this:

| year | x | x_err | y | y_err |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | n | n | n | n |
| 2 | n | n | n | n |
| 3 | n | n | n | n |

I'd like to make a NetCDF file where there would be two variables [x_variabel] & [y_variable], which would be two dimensional (as in they would include the value, and the error value).

I know how to make a simple DataFrame and turn that into a NetCDF i.e.

```
import xarray as xr
Data = pd.DataFrame({'Year': Years,
                     'x': x,
                     'x_err': x_err
                     'y': y,
                     'y_err':y_err
                      }) 
Data = xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(Data.set_index(["Year"]))
Data.to_netcdf("NetCDF.nc")
```

This creates a standard NetCDF where year is the dimension and I have four variables.

But how can I make a NetCDF where instead of "x" and "x_err" being different variables, they would be a single variable, where "x" would be x_variable[0] and "x_err" would be x_variable[1]? This would be a significant improvement to my workflow.

```
Data = pd.DataFrame({'Year': Years,
                     'x': [x,x_err],
                     'y': [y,y_err]
                      })
```

Does not work, since it considers 'x' and 'y' to have lengths of just two. Is it possible to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by stacking the array. As an example for x:

```
import pandas as pd
test = {"x":{"1":3,"2":4,"3":5},"x_err":{"1":0.3,"2":0.4,"3":0.5},"y":{"1":30,"2":40,"3":50},"y_err":{"1":300,"2":400,"3":500}}

df = pd.DataFrame(test)

data = xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df)
data[["x", "x_err"]].to_stacked_array("x", ["index"])

>>> <xarray.DataArray 'x' (index: 3, x: 2)>
array([[3. , 0.3],
       [4. , 0.4],
       [5. , 0.5]])
Coordinates:
  * index     (index) object '1' '2' '3'
  * x         (x) object MultiIndex
  * variable  (x) object 'x' 'x_err'
```

and then you can index like this:

```
test = data[["x", "x_err"]].to_stacked_array("x", ["index"])
test[0,1]

>>> <xarray.DataArray 'x' ()>
array(0.3)
Coordinates:
    index     <U1 '1'
    x         object ('x_err',)
    variable  <U5 'x_err'
```